# Assigning vector values from a variable generated inside for loop matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vector, char

In Matlab I am trying to assign values of a variable generated within a for-loop to an array.

```
for i=1:4
S = 2*i;
P(i) = S;
end
```

`S` is generated within the for loop and all the values it will have are: `2, 4, 6 and 8`.

Now I want to assign each of these values of S to an array `P` such that I want

`P(1) = 2, P(2) = 4, P(3) = 6, P(4) = 8`

But the for-loop I have included does not work and I have no idea why. First of all it creates a `char` rather than creating and array. Secondly, none of the values are added and at the end P is empty.

I am not sure why its not working? Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Try to first allocate P   by `P=zeros(4,1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a variable `P` which is a char. Subscript assigning does not change the type of the variable. Delete it using `clear P` and you get what you want. Alternatively you can overwrite P with zeros as Photon suggested.

This may also be solved without a loop:

```
P=2.*[1:4]
```

or:

```
P=2:2:8
```